# Writing a simple bash like command prompt, that supports auto completion (handles tab key)

Tags: linux, perl, command-prompt

I was trying to implement a simple shell prompt, that only needs to handle internal commands, I tried `Term::ReadLine`, but that one doesn't handle Tab key like bash does, so I'm wondering what else could I do now.

Comment: What kind of OS do you use? Would using AutoHotKey be an option? What kind of behaviour do you expect and in which environments (aps)?

Comment: @RobertIlbrink linux only, auto completion just list all possible commands, they are all scalar strings

Comment: Can't be of any help here, too long ago for me.

Comment: The C `readline` API has functions for that, but I don't know if Perl wraps them.

Comment: Which is your primary problem: getting autocomplete working, or getting it to respond to the tab key?

Comment: @Basile it does, at least if you use Term::ReadLine::Gnu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search on CPAN yields [`Term::Completion`](https://metacpan.org/module/Term%3a%3aCompletion) and [`Term::Complete`](https://metacpan.org/module/Term%3a%3aComplete)

```
use Term::Completion qw( Complete );

my $result = Complete($prompt, @choices);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Term::Readline` is a factory wrapper around many possible implementations of the readline interface. The default one you get is a fairly minimal one implemented in pure perl, called `Term::Readline::Perl`; it lacks such things as tab-complete.

If however you install `Term::Readline::Gnu`, that does have tab-complete, and should be used in preference to the pureperl one, by `Term::Readline`.